# go - How can you serve static files with route based authorization with JWT in Gin?

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

I am trying to serve videos from a directory. I know how to do that (`r.Static("/videos", "./videos")`) but I have a directory for each user in there like `/videos/testuser/video.mp4`. I have implemented a login system with JWT, but how would I got about only letting `testuser` access `/videos/testuser` and `user1` access `/videos/user1`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the UserID in JWT and parse the JWT claims whenever someone downloads the video. Use `fmt.Sprintf("videos/%s/video.mp4", jwt.UserId)` to get the desired directory depends on different user.